# How do I built a boxplot much better with extreme outlier using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataset with extreme outlier. I am trying to build boxplot using following code

```
ggplot(arrange_df, aes(x = "", y = idleS)) + geom_boxplot()
```

It display the plot like this

[image]

How do I present the boxplot much better with extreme outlier. Thanks for any help or suggestion

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation of another graph that shows outliers better? Or how you can make a boxplot look better with outliers? If it's the latter I'm not sure you really have an option, maybe just remove the outlier and make note of it somewhere else.

Comment: Given the drastic difference in value, is the outlier value actually a correct/valid data entry? If not, it would be best practice to remove it.

Comment: Try adding `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1e6))` To your plot. If your box plot is still squashed, reduce the 1e6 until it looks normal (I can't be any more specific here because you have not included your data)

Comment: For some reason I have to include the outlier. I can't remove it. Is there any better way to present these extreme outlier in boxplot or any other plot ?